# How to build an iterator on std::list<std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>> that will address std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I am writing a custom implementation of hash map (similar to `std::unordered_map`) and one of the steps is the following:

There is a `std::list` of `<KeyType, ValueType>` pairs, which contains all the objects stored in the hashtable. I need to build an iterator that would run over the list, hovewer, it must address not `std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>` but `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` (so that the user can't change the keys), so I can't use the built-in list iterator.

So how it can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Write a wrapper over `std::list<...>::iterator`, or actually store `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` in the list.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat A wrapper probably won't help. At the end of the day, `*it` for iterator `it` over `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` must return a reference to `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>`, but there's no object of this type to refer to. Well, I suppose it could return a proxy object a la `std::vector<bool>`, and then give up on meeting container requirements.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unfortunately, storing `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` in the list is not a solution, cause there is a couple of functions in the implementation of list which copy elements, so the program crashes

Comment: First, `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` is copyable (assuming `KeyType` and `ValueType` are). Second, `std::list<T>` should not require `T` to be copyable. What problems with what functions of `list` do you have, specifically? Perhaps you should concentrate on solving that part.

Comment: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const int, int>& std::pair<const int, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const int, int>&)’` is appearing. That is because of `_M_assign_dispatch` function in list.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's unclear why you need `operator=`.

Comment: That's not copying. That's assigning - an attempt to modify the element in-place. Your implementation shouldn't need to do that. Figure out where you try to, and find a way to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah you were right, there was a line in tests which performed the copying, it is possible to just make a lst of `std::pair<const Type, Type>`